# Angular 6 Testing - Service with reference to helper that uses HttpClient

Tags: angular, karma-jasmine, angular6, angular-httpclient

Last week I upgraded our application from Angular 5.8 to 6. With this I changed the use of HttpModule and Http to the use of HttpClientModule and HttpClient. So far so good, the frontend seems to work like expected. Only now some service tests are failing and I am trying to fix them. Basically I have two types of services:

1. A service that directly uses the HttpClient.

   CustomService:

   ```
   import { HttpClient } from "@angular/common/http";
   import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
   import { map } from "rxjs/operators";
   import { Observable} from "rxjs";

   @Injectable()
   export class CustomService {
       constructor(private readonly http: HttpClient) { }

       someMethod(): Observable<boolean> {
           return this.http.get("api/some-url").pipe(
               map(res => <boolean>res) }))
           );
       }
   }
   ```
2. A service that uses a ServiceHelper, which uses the HttpClient.

   CustomService:

   ```
   import { HttpHeaders } from "@angular/common/http";
   import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
   import { Observable } from "rxjs";

   import { SomeRequest } from "../Models/SomeRequest";
   import { SomeResult } from "../Models/SomeResult";
   import { ServiceHelper } from "./../Helpers/servicehelper";

   @Injectable()
   export class CustomService {
       constructor(readonly serviceHelper: ServiceHelper) { }

       someMethod(): Observable<SomeResult> {
           const request = {} as SomeRequest;
           const headers = new HttpHeaders({ "Content-Type": "application/json" });
           const options = { headers: headers };

           return this.serviceHelper
               .post<SomeRequest, SomeResult>("api/some-url", request, options);
       }
   }
   ```

   ServiceHelper:

   ```
   import { HttpClient } from "@angular/common/http";
   import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
   import { map } from "rxjs/operators";
   import { Observable } from "rxjs";

   import { Result } from "../Models/Result";

   @Injectable()
   export class ServiceHelper {
       constructor(readonly http: HttpClient) { }

       post<Req, Res extends Result>(url: string, request: Req, options): Observable<Res> {
           return this.http.post(url, request, options).pipe(
               map(data => (data as any) as Res)
           );
       }
   }
   ```

Tests for the first service are already working again, by doing something like this:

```
import { TestBed } from "@angular/core/testing";
import { HttpClientTestingModule, HttpTestingController } from "@angular/common/http/testing";
import { HttpResponse } from "@angular/common/http";

import { CustomService } from "./custom.service";

describe("service tests", () => {
    let service: CustomService;
    let httpClient: HttpTestingController;

    beforeEach(() => {
        TestBed.configureTestingModule({
            imports: [HttpClientTestingModule],
            providers: [CustomService]
        });
        service = TestBed.get(CustomService);
        httpClient = TestBed.get(HttpTestingController);
    });

    it("should pass", () => {
        service.someMethod().subscribe(result => {
            expect(result).toBe(true);
        });

        httpClient.expectOne("api/some-url").event(
            new HttpResponse<boolean>({ body: true }));
    });
});
```

For the second service (that uses the ServiceHelper) I want to do something like above in the beforeEach statement. I tried a couple of things in the configureTestingModule with adding providers and/or imports, but mostly I get a StaticInjectorError after running the tests.

Ho can I write tests for the second kind of services? Hopefully someone can help me further!

Comment: can you show what did you try please

Comment: I fixed it with adding: { provide: ServiceHelper, useClass: ServiceHelper } to the providers array.

Answer (score 3):

Fixed it by adding { provide: ServiceHelper, useClass: ServiceHelper } to the providers array. The fixed configureTestingModule looks like:

```
TestBed.configureTestingModule({
        imports: [HttpClientTestingModule],
        providers: [
            CustomService,
            { provide: ServiceHelper, useClass: ServiceHelper }
        ]
    })
```